# Ajax redirects to the url with preventDefault()

Tags: django, ajax

I'm using Django for an app that allows you to search and save recipes. I'm trying to have a form on a search results page that allows you to click 'save' and creates an object to the database without reloading the page. In the current setup when I click on the 'save' button for the form with id="add_form" I get redirected to a new url (add/) even though I've included preventDefault().

I thought this was due to me including the form action={%url 'add' %} however, I've tried removing the form action but that gave me a multiValueDictKeyError for raw_input = request.POST['ingredients'] so I thought it was calling the incorrect view function views.recipes instead of views.add. I've read some other ajax guides that explicitly state a form action so I thought that would help with the incorrect view function being called.

views.py

```
def recipes(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check for dietary restrictions
        restrictions = request.POST.getlist('restrictions')
        # format input ingredients
        raw_input = request.POST['ingredients']

    ...

    return render(request, 'recipes/recipes.html', {'results': results})
    else:
    return render(request, 'recipes/recipes.html', {'error': 'Please search for a recipe'})

@csrf_protect
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        image = request.POST['image']
        source = request.POST['source']
        user = request.user
        try:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.get(image=image, title=title, source=source)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.create(image=image, title=title, source=source)
        finally:
            recipe.users.add(user)
            recipe.save()

    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
else:
    return JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', views.add, name='add'),
    path('', views.recipes, name='recipes'),
 ]
```

html file

```
{% block content %}
...
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="{% url 'add' %}" id="add_form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="image" name="image" value="{{ result.image }}">
     <input type="hidden" id="title" name="title" value="{{ result.title }}">
     <input type="hidden" id="source" name="source" value="{{ result.source }}">

     <button type="submit" name="recipe" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Save</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
{%  endblock %}


{% block javascript %}

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add_form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( "form submitted");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        async: 'false',
        cache: 'false',
        url:'{% url 'add' %}',
        data:{
            image:$('#image').val(),
            title:$('#title').val(),
            source:$('#source').val(),
        },
        success:function(){
            alert("Saved Recipe")
        }
    })
 })
 })

</script>
```

I'm expecting any clicks to the save button to stay on the same page without a reload and to call views.add which will save/create an object to the database

Answer (score 0):

Change the url to `$(this).attr('action')`. It will automatically get the url from the form instead of explicitly defining it again while making ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        async: 'false',
        cache: 'false',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),,
        data:{
            image:$('#image').val(),
            title:$('#title').val(),
            source:$('#source').val(),
        },
        success:function(){
            alert("Saved Recipe")
        }
    })
```

Comment: It still brings me to http://localhost:8000/recipes/add/ instead of staying on the same page

Comment: @MichaelLi Change `$("#add_form").on('submit', function(e)` to `$("#add_form").submit(function(e) `

Comment: @MichaelLi let me know if that works, i will change the answer accordingly

Comment: that doesn't work for me either. I've read that (form).submit(function(e) is just the shorthand version of (form).on('submit, function(e). I've also tried var 
form = document.getElementById("add_form")
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();